# Estou produzindo uma especie de formulário, porém na idade as pessoas colocam (idade + "anos")

Tags: c#

Estou produzindo uma especie de formulário, porém na idade as pessoas colocam (idade + "anos"), porem a variável é tipo int então não funciona, gostaria de saber se existe algum método de mandar uma mensagem para o cliente quando ele inserir uma letra no campo idade como por exemplo.

```
int idade;
console.write("idade:");
idade = convert.toint32(console.readline());
if(int nao for numero)
{
   faça alguma coisa;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o código esta comentando explicando o seu funcionamento.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        int idade;

        // Console e Write são iniciados com letras maiusculas 
        Console.Write("idade:");

        // Console, Read e Line são iniciados com letras maiusculas
        string idadeString = Console.ReadLine();

        // Se foi digitado um número inteiro
        if(Int32.TryParse(idadeString, out idade))
        {
           Console.Write("idade: " + idade);
        }else{
            Console.Write("Favor inserir um valor inteiro");
        }
    }
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: muito bom, eu sei q se inici acom letras maiusculas aqui no exemplo eu fiz tudo minusculo pelo tempo

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de fazer isto. A mais simples seria com `int.TryParse` onde ele irá tentar converter uma string para um inteiro. Caso não consiga, retorna `false` e não lança exceção alguma. A versão `int.Parse` gera uma exceção.

Exemplo:

```
Console.Write("Digite a idade:");
bool isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int idade);
if (isNumber)
{
    // use a variável 'IDADE' aqui
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite apenas números para idade");
}
```

> Converte a representação de cadeia de caracteres de um número no inteiro com sinal de 32 bits equivalente. Um valor retornado indica se a operação foi bem-sucedida.

Referência: [System.Int32.TryPase (msdn)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score -2):

Eu usaria um IF:

```
if(($idade > 0) || ($idade < 99)){
  echo "aqui vai o campo";
} else {  
echo "insira uma idade válida";
}
```

Comment: O Josla procura uma resposta em C# e não em php, e ele quer identificar se um determinado valor que foi digitado é inteiro ou não.